# App Engine Deployer Role/ insufficent GCP permissions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-iam

Working on a github action for deploying an app engine project I ran into this error:

```
Permissions error fetching application [apps/your-app-id]. 
Please make sure that you have permission to view applications on the project
and that serviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
has the App Engine Deployer (roles/appengine.deployer) role.
```

I double checked the permission in IAM, but to no avail. I even went so far to use the cli to verify the service accounts permissions. What could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you'll get this error message if you haven't enabled billing for your project, such as setting up a new staging environment.